# Pitivi: how to render a project

Tags: video, pitivi

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Pitivi 0.94 and I just created a new project and did some video editing in it. Now I want to render a video file in any format, but that seems to be not so easy.

I tried nearly all formats and codecs provided by pitivi and each of them either renders video with rubbish quality (about 1 kbps, no matter what bitrate I set in pitivi) or just crashes. Searching online I didn't find any render setting that would produce acceptable video quality.

So the question is: has anyone ever managed to get watchable quality output from pitivi and if so, what settings should be used for this?

Comment: really? This question posted March 2015 is a duplicate of November  2015 question?